# How to trim space less than n times?

Tags: rust, texttrimming

How to eliminate up to n spaces at the beginning of each line?

For example, when trim 4 space:

- `"     5"` ->`" 5"`
- `"    4"` ->`"4"`
- `"   3"` ->`"3"`

```rust
const INPUT:&str = "    4\n  2\n0\n\n      6\n";
const OUTPUT:&str = "4\n2\n0\n\n  6\n";
#[test]
fn main(){
    assert_eq!(&trim_deindent(INPUT,4), OUTPUT)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was about to comment [`textwrap::dedent`](https://docs.rs/textwrap/0.11.0/textwrap/fn.dedent.html), but then I noticed `"2"`, which has less than 4 spaces. So you wanted it to keep removing spaces, if there is any up until 4.

Just writing a quick solution, it could look something like this:

Your assert will pass, but note that lines ending in `\r\n` will be converted to `\n`, as [`lines`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.str.html#method.lines) does not provide a way to differentiate between `\n` and `\r\n`.

```rust
fn trim_deindent(text: &str, max: usize) -> String {
    let mut new_text = text
        .lines()
        .map(|line| {
            let mut max = max;
            line.chars()
                // Skip while `c` is a whitespace and at most `max` spaces
                .skip_while(|c| {
                    if max == 0 {
                        false
                    } else {
                        max -= 1;
                        c.is_whitespace()
                    }
                })
                .collect::<String>()
        })
        .collect::<Vec<_>>()
        .join("\n");

    // Did the original `text` end with a `\n` then add it again
    if text.ends_with('\n') {
        new_text.push('\n');
    }

    new_text
}
```

If you want to retain both `\n` and `\r\n` then you can go a more complex route of scanning through the string, and thus avoiding using [`lines`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.str.html#method.lines).

```rust
fn trim_deindent(text: &str, max: usize) -> String {
    let mut new_text = String::new();

    let mut line_start = 0;
    loop {
        let mut max = max;

        // Skip `max` spaces
        let after_space = text[line_start..].chars().position(|c| {
            // We can't use `is_whitespace` here, as that will skip past `\n` and `\r` as well
            if (max == 0) || !is_horizontal_whitespace(c) {
                true
            } else {
                max -= 1;
                false
            }
        });

        if let Some(after_space) = after_space {
            let after_space = line_start + after_space;

            let line = &text[after_space..];
            // Find `\n` or use the line length (if it's the last line)
            let end = line
                .chars()
                .position(|c| c == '\n')
                .unwrap_or_else(|| line.len());

            // Push the line (including the line ending) onto `new_text`
            new_text.push_str(&line[..=end]);

            line_start = after_space + end + 1;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    new_text
}

#[inline]
fn is_horizontal_whitespace(c: char) -> bool {
    (c != '\r') && (c != '\n') && c.is_whitespace()
}
```

Comment: @mcarton how would you take a single `&str` and return multiple separate `&str` without allocating? I can see an alternative of returning `Vec<&str>` but that would equally allocate.

Comment: Never mind, I misread the OP and though it only needed to handle one line.

Comment: Instead of `.collect::<Vec<_>>().join("\n")`, you can collect into a `String` directly.

Comment: @Aloso how do you add the `\n` then?